# What is the Big-O complexity of nested for loops of increasing length

Tags: java, big-o

I'm new to the Big O notation and I am a little bit confused on how the following code plays into the Big O notation. In this situation `n` is just the length of an array and as you can see the two inner for loops are iterating through `n^2` and `n * 4`. How does that play into the Big O notation? At first glance I thought it was `n^3` however I am unsure.

```
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j < n*n; j++)
        sum += data[i] * data[j];
      for (int j=0; j < 4*n; j++)
        sum += data[i] + data[j];
    }
```

Comment: For loops like this, you don't need a O( ); you can calculate the exact number of iterations (for instance the exact number of times that a `sum +=` instruction is evaluated).

Comment: I think you're right: it's O(n³). Why are you unsure?

Comment: @khelwood "I think you're right" why are you unsure? :)

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm just cagey.

Comment: The first inner loop performs exactly `n*n` iterations. The second inner loop performs exactly `4*n` iterations. Both of these loop are repeated at every iteration of the outer loop. The outer loop performs exactly `n` iterations. Hence the total number of evaluations of `sum+=` is `n * (n*n + 4*n)`, which is n³+4n², which is O(n³).

Comment: @khelwood I'm unsure because I know in the last for loop the 4 becomes irrelevant as the dataset grows making it O(n) however in the second for loop there is no constant. It is n*n which seems very significant to me. I don't know how it effects things.

Answer (score 2):

```
O(n * (O(c1 * n^2) + O(c2 * 4 * n))) =
O(n * (O(n^2) + O(n)) =
O(n * O(n^2)) =
O(n ^ 3)
```

Because sum (+), assignment (=), multiplication (*) and array access ([i]) cost constant.
So you are right.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop iterates n times. For each iteration of the first loop second loop iterates n*n times. Therefore the total number of iterations of the second loop is n*(n*n). Furthermore for each iteration of the first loop third loop iterates 4*n times. Therefore the total number of iterations of the third loop is n*(4*n).

Hence complexity is O(n*n*n + n*4*n) -> O(n^3 + n^2) -> O(n^3).

You are right!!